# Define private variable outside of the function which going to be used by new creation pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype-programming

This question is simplified version of my old question [Adding scope variable to a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226559/adding-scope-variable-to-a-constructor). Question is simple can I add priv variable to the fu()'s scope without changing the function? (not adding inside of the function block)

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxu5M/2/)

Here is the code:

```
fff = function() {
    alert('constructed');
    //alert(priv);
};
pro = {
    pub: 'public'
}
var make = function(fu, pro) {

    var priv = 'private';
    fu.prototype = pro
    return function() {
      return new fu();
    };
};

var cls = make(fff, pro);
var obj = cls();

alert(obj.pub);​
```

As you can see if you de-comment the

```
//alert(priv);
```

line Uncaught ReferenceError: priv is not defined error.

I need a way to redifine the scope of the fu() function object.

Comment: Question. Why wrap 'return new fu()' in a function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `fu` object listed, but I think the answer is "yes", you can add a private variable without changing the "function".  Now, I may be missing something, but if I follow you, here is what you want:

```
var fu = {
           DoStuff: function(someVar){
            alert(someVar);
}
};
```

Then later in your code:

```
fu["NewPrivateVar"] = "something!";
```

Or in dot notation:

```
fu.NewPrivateVar = "someting!";
```

Finally:

```
fu.DoStuff(fu.NewPrivateVar);
```

Results in:

```
"something!"
```

Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: unfortunately that's not what I try to do. If you run the code on console you can see the obj object has got a property named 'pub'. I want to push a var into the function (fff function) but I dont want it to be reachable from the obj object. (sorry for my insufficient english skills)

Comment: side note: I think your syntax is adding static properties. I use it offenly

Comment: Matthew this means `fu` is no longer a function, so you can't create instances with `new fu()`, and `NewPrivateVar` is _not_ actually private because any code with a reference to the `fu` object can access `fu.NewPrivateVar`. (Also if you have to manually pass a parameter to `fu.DoStuff()` then that could be _any_ value.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the scope of the function by calling it from inside an object or a closure.

You can however add the variable to the scope of the function, i.e. in the global scope:

```
window.priv = 'private';
```

That will make the function work without changes, but the variable isn't very private...

Comment: As you say... 'but the variable isn't very private...'

Comment: Well can you suggest any alternative syntax for me.

Comment: Well, if you don't want the data in the prototype, the only way to send data to the constructor is in the global scope, or as a parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/7dCge/